# LINQ Statement Doesn't Compile

Tags: linq, entity-framework

This statement won't compile:

```
query = from g in context.GridViews 
   join f in context.GridViewFavorites on g.ID equals f.GridViewID into gf
   where g.GridTypeID == id && ( g.IsShared == true || g.RepID == me.clsRep.OID) 
   && f.RepID == me.clsRep.OID
   select g;
```

The compiler error is this (and it's underlining the last part of the where clause:

> The name 'f' does not exist in the current context

It's logical SQL counterpart would be:

```
declare @RepID int
declare @GridTypeID int
select @RepID=15, @GridTypeID=5

select g.*,f.*
from
   GridViews g
   left outer join GridViewFavorites f on f.GridViewID = g.ID
where
   g.GridTypeID = @GridTypeID and (g.IsShared = 1 or g.RepID == @RepID) 
   and f.RepID == @RepID
```

**NOTE:** per @hdv 's good catch the SQL sample should actually be:

```
select g.*,f.*
from
   GridView g
   left outer join GridViewFavorite f on f.GridViewID = g.ID and f.RepID = @RepID
where
   g.GridTypeID = @GridTypeID and (g.IsShared = 1 or g.RepID = @RepID)
```

Comment: Do you realise that your SQL counterpart functions as an inner join? When no `GridViewFavorites` is found, `f.RepID` will never compare equal to any parameter. If that's what you want, it can be simpler than the answers you've got so far.

Comment: @hvd, good call!  I wrote the SQL kind of quick hand as you can tell by the remnants of the scattered == operators.  I'll post the correct SQL in the question. To answer your query, yes, the answers below are going after what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the "into" part of your join - once you've joined "into" a group, the join variable (`f` in this case) is out of scope - you've got to use `gf` instead. Alternatively, given that you're not actually *using* `gf` in your query at all, maybe you should just get rid of the `into gf` part entirely so it's a normal join instead of a group join.

However, that won't give you a left outer join. If you want a left outer join, you might want:

```
query = from g in context.GridViews 
   join f in context.GridViewFavorites on g.ID equals f.GridViewID into gf
   from f2 in gf.DefaultIfEmpty()
   where g.GridTypeID == id && (g.IsShared == true || g.RepID == me.clsRep.OID) 
   && (f2 == null || f2.RepID == me.clsRep.OID)
   select g;
```

Comment: Thanks @Skeet for the padding your stats on my question.  One follow-up question: after I represent the join of "g" and "f" as "f2", why are you able to reference "g" in the where clause and not "f"?

Comment: @sisdog: Basically when you have a `join x ... into y` clause, the `x` range variable is only in scope within that join clause, because the result of it is the group. Any other range variables which were already in scope stay in scope. If you were using `group ... into ...` *then* all the earlier range variables would be out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The left-join pattern for LINQ goes like this:

```
join f in context.GridViewFavorites on g.ID equals f.GridViewID into gf
from f in gf.DefaultIfEmpty() //missing
```

More information is available on Stack Overflow and Google.

Comment: Thanks @usr, I never thought to check Stack Overflow or Google.  Great advice!

Answer (score 0):

The `where` clause acts on the joined result, so the `f` variable is not in scope.